# Proving that a trig limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I formally prove $$\not\exists\lim_{x\to 0} 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$$ using [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#cite_note-Olsen2004-1) ?

Comment: I would suggest you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$, and $x \neq 0$, then
$$f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$$
By Darboux's theorem, $f'$ has the intermediate value property. For each positive integer $n$, evaluate $f'$ at $x = 1/((2n+1)\pi)$ and $x = 1/(2n\pi)$:
$$f'\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}\right) = -\cos((2n+1)\pi) = 1$$
and
$$f'\left(\frac{1}{2n\pi}\right) = -\cos(2n\pi) = -1$$
Therefore, by the intermediate value property, given any $y\in [-1,1]$, there is some $x \in [1/((2n+1)\pi), 1/(2n\pi)]$ such that $f'(x) = y$.

For any $\delta > 0$, there is some $n$ such that the interval $[1/((2n+1)\pi), 1/(2n\pi)]$ is contained in $(-\delta, \delta)$. Therefore $f'$ takes on every value between $-1$ and $+1$ in the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$. This means that $f'$ cannot have a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Note that we didn't really need the intermediate value property to reach this conclusion. It was sufficient to observe that $f'$ assumes the values $+1$ and $-1$ in every interval $(-\delta, \delta)$.

---

**edit** in response to the question raised in the comments:

Let $\epsilon = 1$. If $f'$ has a limit $L$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, then for some $\delta > 0$ we must have $|f'(x) - L| < \epsilon = 1$ for all $0 < |x| < \delta$.

But there is no $L$ which can satisfy this requirement since for every $\delta > 0$, we can find some $x_1, x_2 \in (-\delta, \delta)$ such that $f'(x_1) = 1$ and $f(x_2) = -1$.

Therefore,
$$2 = |f'(x_2) - f'(x_1)| \leq |f'(x_2) - L| + |f'(x_1) - L|$$
so if one of the terms on the right hand side is smaller than $1$, the other must be greater than $1$.

---

Also, note that $f'$ is continuous for all $x \neq 0$, so we didn't need Darboux's theorem to conclude that it has the intermediate value property. So this exercise seems kind of silly to me.

Comment: But that's (regarding your comment that the IVProperty was not needed) just saying that the image of an interval is also an interval, which is the IVP itself, right?

Comment: @user71487: But we didn't require the fact that $f'$ assumes every value between $-1$ and $+1$. Even if we only know that $f'$ takes on the two values $+1$ and $-1$ in every interval $(-\delta,\delta)$, then $f'$ cannot have a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I thought I had understood the answer at first, but I stumbled upon some late doubts, so I apologize asking for clarifications after it's been the chosen answer. Why is it that we conclude $f'$ cannot have a limit as $x\to 0$ from the fact $f'$ takes on every value between $-1$ and $+1$ in the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
(1) $x \rightarrow 0$ instead of $x \rightarrow \infty$ in "...limit $L$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$..."?
(2)$2 = |f'(x_2) - f'(x_1)| \leq |f'(x_2) - L| + |L - f'(x_1)|$?

Comment: @user71487: Yes, sorry. Fixed now.